# How to past the text without formatting loss in MathType editor

Tags: mathml, equations, mathtype

I would like to convert the 'text to MathType' in word document.

For example I have already keyed the text "A<sup>2</sup> + B<sup>2</sup> = C<sup>2</sup>", instead of keyed in MathType editor. So I have tried to copy and paste that text into MathType editor, while doing so the superscript's style is lose in that content, i.e. it past like A2 + B2 = C2.

Is there is any option to convert the text into MathType without formatting lose? Or paste the text into MathType Editor Window without formatting lose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got the answer from Design Science, it is bug in older version5.2 MathType editor. However they said it has been fixed in new version MathType editor, but I have to test it!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know 1) *how* did you "key the text..." (i.e., in Word's equation editor, or just using styled text in Word), and 2) are you using Windows or Mac?

Comment: I using Windows OS and just using styled text in Word

Comment: Then there's no reason it wouldn't have worked, whether from Word or from here. It doesn't even matter if you style the variables as italic. I work for WIRIS Science (formerly Design Science, creators of MathType), and if you'll write our support at support@dessci.com, we'll be glad to help you further.

Comment: Okey Bob, I will send the email from my official mail ID.